# Is there any way to "capture" local scope template variables (akin to a lisp special) and use as default?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// this code below won't compile unless at this point there is already
// a typename rate
// using rate = std::integral_constant<int, 10>;

template<typename rate=rate> void functionA()
{
  static_assert(rate::value > 5);
  std::cout << "functionA: " << rate::value << std::endl;
}

template<typename rate> void loop()
{
    functionA<std::integral_constant<int, 50>>(); // => prints "functionA: 50"
    functionA();  // <- I would like this call to infer loop's functions's rate template type (which would be 20)
}

void other()
{
   using rate = std::integral_constant<int, 12>;
   functionA(); // => prints "functionA: 12"
}

void bare_loop()
{
   functionA(); // should give compile time-error: no 'rate' in semantic scope
}

int main() {

  loop<std::integral_constant<int, 20>>();
  
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to write a templated function which has a default parameter value which remains undeclared until compilation is necessary.

The above shows the most minimal piece of code to express this idea.

What I'm trying to achieve is directly inspired by Lisp's variable capture mechanism (lexical and dynamic scope).

To be clear: this is *entirely* a compile-time problem and solution.

Is this possible in the current state of affaires of C++?

Comment: It won't work any better than `void f(int x); void g(int x) { f(); }` A call to `f` won't magically look for an identifier `x` to take as an argument. You don't want a seemingly inconsequential change in the function declaration (e.g. `void f(int y)`) to have wide-ranging consequences through the whole program. Same in your example - the name of the template parameter can be changed by the author of `functionA` without affecting the rest of the program, and that's a good thing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: understood that it won't work by magic. However, for instance, having a global variable called `int _g;` and calling `int f(int x=-1) { return (x==-1? _g : x); }` would do as intended. The problem is that that is entirely runtime and not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Picking up a global variable is different from picking up a local variable at the call site that just happens to have the same name as the function's parameter. Which is what you appear to want to do. That (thankfully) doesn't work.

Comment: As I have stated, I'm trying to achieve a concept called dynamic scope capture in lisp. It is not about "global" variables. It's entirely a compile time concept. The global variable example I gave was simply in response to your point that `f()` can't and doesn't magically infer an argument (and this is by syntax).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lisp. In C++, the name of the template parameter (or regular function parameter) doesn't have any meaning outside of the definition of that template or function. `void f(int x);` and `void f(int y);` are two declarations of the same function; `template <int rate> void f();` and `template <int foobar> void f();` are two declarations of the same template. The feature you are looking for doesn't exist in C++ (and I, for one, feel that's a good thing; it sounds like a disaster to me).

Comment: The only way I know of to make the example work is using macros, e.g. `#define functionA_Auto functionA<rate>`.

Comment: Yes, I am hoping at some point that a mechanism of the newer metaprogramming constructs will allow to not have to use the pre-processor. 

I have also attempted using namespace injection. e.g. having a `using rate = something` in a 'default' namespace, while trying to instantiate the template code inside the local namespace. Alas, the template parameter resolution is constrained to the declaration semantic scope.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure if I understood what you intended, but if you want is a function that could either take the parameter rate at compile time or at runtime, well, one possibility would be to use a default parameter in function "functionA", determined by the template parameter. So you can define the default in compile time, and override it in runtime if needed.

I leave an example below in case it helps, however I can't understand what it the desired use case, and it can be possibly
a bad design:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

constexpr int infer() { return 123; }

const int MIN_RATE_LIM = 5;
template<int t_rate=infer()> void functionA(const int rate = t_rate)
{
  assert(rate > MIN_RATE_LIM);
  std::cout << "functionA: " << rate << std::endl;
}

template<int rate> void loop()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
  {
    functionA<50>();
    functionA<rate>();
    functionA<rate>(12);  // <- 12 will overlap the value 10 in this line
  }
}

int main() {

  loop<10>();
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, I'm not trying to mix runtime at all in there. I'm trying to make it so that whatever `loop`'s rate is, I can infer (at compile time, with compile time static asserts) that all the functions I'm calling from `loop` fullfil a certain compile time property.

I'd like to be able to call `functionA` from both `loop1`, `loop2` ... `loopn` and never specify the rate template parameter of `functionA` and instead let the compiler infer it.

Comment: Hum, so you would like the functionA to take the rate of its "enclosing" loop function maybe? One possibility, in case functionA is only used inside loop, is to make loop a class and functionA a member function. Well, there is a lot of possibilities. I am not fluent in Lisp, and indeed C++ compiler does not have such feature, but there are many possibilities to emulate that, depending on your specific use case. C++ is primarily an object oriented language, but contexts in C++ are usually managed through function or global scopes, namespaces, and also classes and objects.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it: functionA takes the rate of the enclosing loop.

The most important aspect of what I'm looking for is static compile time enforcement of a certain property of the code. Classes are how I'd do this using runtime checks, however I'm trying to solve this challenge.

Comment: Another possibility is the use of the concept of "functors" (function objects). You can take a look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functors-in-cpp/#:~:text=A%20functor%20(or%20function%20object,that%20overloads%20the%20operator(). 
Using such technique, you can define objects that "behave" like functions, so they can store other member functions used internally, which will have access to member variables. You can also pass arguments by reference, there are many possibilities, it depends on your exact user case. And function pointers can be of interest too.